# WebStorm not recognizing node.js methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

I've just started learning node.js and I'm using WebStorm 11 as my IDE. For some reason WebStorm doesn't recognize `writeHead` method:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

I've checked that node.js core is enabled in JavaScript libraries.

This is what "Node.js and NPM" window looks like:

[image]

I've looked online for other answers and no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

From the preferences menu, check `Languages & Frameworks` -> `Node.js and NPM`. Code Assistance should be enabled.

Comment: unfortunately i dont have that option as can be seen here: http://i.imgur.com/UADQ92D.jpg

Answer (score 0):

please try upgrading to the most recent version (11.0.3) -[WEB-19190](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19190) is fixed there. Note that you need disabling and then re-enabling Node.js Core library